# Back Failure - Unknown error

Tags: sql-server, backup

My backup job is getting failed sometimes and throwing error as below.

> Started:  00:15:01  Finished: 02:59:59  Elapsed:  9896.17 seconds. 
>   The package execution failed.  The step failed.

When i googled this i found different answers.

I have figured out something new in this.

**Backup job starts at: 00:15Hrs and takes 2-3 hours to complete the job.
Another job: That update some tables on the database at 02:00Hrs.**

Is the update effecting my backup to fail.?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: What does the specific error say when go you go the job activity history and look at the specific step?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Iam using SQL Server 2008R2 Enterprise.

Comment: Literally that is the only error i have got in the job schedule info....

Comment: @user9192401 You need to use the object explorer and navigate to the history of the job running. Then you can expand out each run and see the steps. It should have more info.  If you are using SQL Server,expand the instance in SSMS, right click the agent, click view activity, right click your job, and click view history. Then expand out the failed run and see what the error is on the step.

Comment: Mate, that is the only information mentioned in the history of job step..

Comment: @user9192401 Then open SSMS and navigate to your SSIS catalog, find the package, and run a report that shows all executions of the package. That will show the specific error.

Comment: Thanks mate. Please find the error in answer because its too long